# How to make SVG the same size as its internal <switch> element?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg of an eye, and am using it as an icon.

This svg has a `<switch>` element inside that contains all the path drawing stuff. When you inspect this `<switch>` element in the javascript console it shows its dimensions as 700px X 500px. The SVG containing it, however is 707px X 707px.

I.e. The SVG has a load of blank space at the top.

I would like to know how to make the SVG the same size as the element contained in it. I need to do this because I want to add a bootstrap tooltip to the image, but the tooltip gets placed much too high above the image because it is padded with all this white space!

I'm new to this SVG stuff - I tried changing the size of the viewport on the SVG, but that just cut the bottom off the image, and left the blank space at the top.

Here is the code for the SVG image:

```
<svg xmlns:x="http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/" xmlns:i="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/" xmlns:graph="http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
  <switch>
    <foreignobject requiredExtensions="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1"></foreignobject>
    <g i:extraneous="self">
      <g>
        <path d="M98.066,57.193c-0.177-0.209-3.629-4.26-9.421-9.081l9.468-11.834l-4.226-3.381l-9.502,11.878     c-0.088-0.065-0.172-0.13-0.261-0.195c-4.013-2.935-8.08-5.37-12.147-7.306l7.502-15.005l-4.841-2.42L66.99,35.146     c-3.896-1.456-7.768-2.423-11.569-2.904l-4.959-17.064l-5.196,1.51l4.418,15.202c-5.41,0.042-11.018,1.142-16.674,3.256     l-7.648-15.297l-4.841,2.42l7.502,15.005c-4.067,1.936-8.134,4.371-12.147,7.306c-0.089,0.065-0.172,0.13-0.261,0.195     L6.113,32.897l-4.226,3.381l9.468,11.834c-5.792,4.82-9.244,8.872-9.421,9.081L0.456,58.94l1.478,1.747     c0.219,0.259,5.455,6.406,13.942,12.613C27.234,81.608,39.034,86,50,86s22.766-4.392,34.124-12.699     c8.487-6.207,13.723-12.354,13.942-12.613l1.478-1.747L98.066,57.193z M71.647,58.94c0,11.514-9.036,20.954-20.388,21.608     c-0.419,0.014-0.837,0.039-1.259,0.039s-0.84-0.025-1.259-0.039C37.389,79.894,28.353,70.454,28.353,58.94     c0-11.936,9.711-21.646,21.647-21.646c0.422,0,0.84,0.025,1.259,0.04C62.611,37.988,71.647,47.427,71.647,58.94z M7.666,58.941     c3.102-3.247,10.491-10.35,20.2-15.537c-3.098,4.401-4.925,9.757-4.925,15.536c0,5.773,1.823,11.126,4.916,15.524     c-3.277-1.745-6.214-3.656-8.681-5.455C13.808,65.097,9.762,61.139,7.666,58.941z M80.824,69.01     c-2.467,1.798-5.404,3.71-8.681,5.455c3.093-4.398,4.916-9.751,4.916-15.524c0-5.773-1.823-11.125-4.916-15.523     c3.277,1.745,6.214,3.656,8.681,5.454c5.37,3.914,9.415,7.872,11.511,10.069C90.24,61.138,86.193,65.096,80.824,69.01z"></path>
        <path d="M39.179,58.94c0,5.98,4.845,10.825,10.818,10.825c5.98,0,10.825-4.845,10.825-10.825c0-5.98-4.845-10.825-10.825-10.825     C44.024,48.114,39.179,52.96,39.179,58.94z M45.941,61.646c-2.239,0-4.056-1.817-4.056-4.055c0-2.246,1.817-4.063,4.056-4.063     c2.239,0,4.056,1.817,4.056,4.063C49.997,59.829,48.18,61.646,45.941,61.646z"></path>
      </g>
    </g>
  </switch>
</svg>
```

I've included it here in a PLNKR so you can see what is happening:
http://plnkr.co/edit/gw1k0vQGon3dxUOVvuDB

Here is the current look of the picture, with new colours for clarity:
[image]

Here is how I would like the image to look (again - ignore the poxy colours...):
[image]

I want to strip all the blank space from the top and the bottom.

Any ideas?

Comment: switch elements always autosize to their contents. BTW SVG is case sensitive so it's foreignObject an not foreignobject.

Comment: dont know how that got changed to a small 'O'.... plnkr updated

Comment: so how do i change the size of the SVG to match the <switch> element?

Comment: Measure it using getBBox and then set the size from that.

Comment: I'm pretty unlearned about svgs.... Is there a way i do it in the <svg> tag without having to do it programaticaly?

Comment: Sure, edit the file and make the width and height whatever you want.

Comment: I put the width and height in the <svg> tag, but when I do that, it proportionally shrinks the <switct> element, which is not what i need.....

Comment: Also decrease the viewBox values (or remove it entirely).

Comment: That doesn't work either - it still just cuts the bottom of the eye and leaves the top blank.... you can see the results in the update plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/gw1k0vQGon3dxUOVvuDB

Comment: Hi Robert, I've update the question to include the pictures showing the problem and the desired outcome.... hope this help clarify things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so? I've added a rect background so it's easy to see the extent of the SVG. All I've done is modify the viewBox so that values match the shape extents.

```html
      <svg viewBox="0 14 100 73" width="100" height="71" xmlns:x="http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/" xmlns:i="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/" xmlns:graph="http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve" overflow="hidden">
        <rect width="100" height="100" fill="lightblue"/>
        <switch>
          <foreignObject requiredExtensions="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1"></foreignobject>
          <g i:extraneous="self">
            <g>
              <path d="M98.066,57.193c-0.177-0.209-3.629-4.26-9.421-9.081l9.468-11.834l-4.226-3.381l-9.502,11.878     c-0.088-0.065-0.172-0.13-0.261-0.195c-4.013-2.935-8.08-5.37-12.147-7.306l7.502-15.005l-4.841-2.42L66.99,35.146     c-3.896-1.456-7.768-2.423-11.569-2.904l-4.959-17.064l-5.196,1.51l4.418,15.202c-5.41,0.042-11.018,1.142-16.674,3.256     l-7.648-15.297l-4.841,2.42l7.502,15.005c-4.067,1.936-8.134,4.371-12.147,7.306c-0.089,0.065-0.172,0.13-0.261,0.195     L6.113,32.897l-4.226,3.381l9.468,11.834c-5.792,4.82-9.244,8.872-9.421,9.081L0.456,58.94l1.478,1.747     c0.219,0.259,5.455,6.406,13.942,12.613C27.234,81.608,39.034,86,50,86s22.766-4.392,34.124-12.699     c8.487-6.207,13.723-12.354,13.942-12.613l1.478-1.747L98.066,57.193z M71.647,58.94c0,11.514-9.036,20.954-20.388,21.608     c-0.419,0.014-0.837,0.039-1.259,0.039s-0.84-0.025-1.259-0.039C37.389,79.894,28.353,70.454,28.353,58.94     c0-11.936,9.711-21.646,21.647-21.646c0.422,0,0.84,0.025,1.259,0.04C62.611,37.988,71.647,47.427,71.647,58.94z M7.666,58.941     c3.102-3.247,10.491-10.35,20.2-15.537c-3.098,4.401-4.925,9.757-4.925,15.536c0,5.773,1.823,11.126,4.916,15.524     c-3.277-1.745-6.214-3.656-8.681-5.455C13.808,65.097,9.762,61.139,7.666,58.941z M80.824,69.01     c-2.467,1.798-5.404,3.71-8.681,5.455c3.093-4.398,4.916-9.751,4.916-15.524c0-5.773-1.823-11.125-4.916-15.523     c3.277,1.745,6.214,3.656,8.681,5.454c5.37,3.914,9.415,7.872,11.511,10.069C90.24,61.138,86.193,65.096,80.824,69.01z"></path>
              <path d="M39.179,58.94c0,5.98,4.845,10.825,10.818,10.825c5.98,0,10.825-4.845,10.825-10.825c0-5.98-4.845-10.825-10.825-10.825     C44.024,48.114,39.179,52.96,39.179,58.94z M45.941,61.646c-2.239,0-4.056-1.817-4.056-4.055c0-2.246,1.817-4.063,4.056-4.063     c2.239,0,4.056,1.817,4.056,4.063C49.997,59.829,48.18,61.646,45.941,61.646z"></path>
            </g>
          </g>
        </switch>
      </svg>
```

Comment: Thats perfect Rob! Looks like I was missing the '14' element of the viewbox... Muchas Gracias...